# Tensorflow: data source can be dynamic?

Tags: tensorflow

In all the examples I've seen in the [Tensorflow documentation](http://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/index.html), the input is parsed from a static source -- typically a file.
Is it possible to construct a graph in which the data come from a different source?  In my use case, data comes from a message string from a server: I want to cast these messages, as they come, in a tensor and use these tensors as inputs for the computation part of the graph.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to provide data from a dynamic source is to put one or more [`tf.placeholder()`](http://tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#placeholders) ops in your graph to represent the input tensors, and use the [feed mechanism](http://tensorflow.org/how_tos/reading_data/index.html#Feeding) to supply different values for those tensors each time you call `run()`. If you do this, it is possible to write arbitrary Python code to generate the input data, which could involve invoking a remote server - or even on the server side handling an incoming request.

If you're doing this in C++, the [`tensorflow::Session`](http://tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/ClassSession.html) class offers the same ability to feed placeholder values, using the [`Session::Run()`](http://tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/ClassSession.html#virtual_Status_tensorflow_Session_Run) method. The fed values must be [`tensorflow::Tensor`](http://tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/ClassTensor.html) objects, which you can create by specifying a datatype and shape (list of dimensions). The `Tensor` objects have methods that allow you to access them as multi-dimensional arrays (like `Tensor::scalar<T>()`, `Tensor::matrix<T>()`, and `Tensor::tensor<T, NDIMS>()`) which allows you to fill in their values as follows:

```c++
tensorflow::Tensor t(DT_FLOAT, tensorflow::TensorShape({2, 2}));
t.matrix()(0, 0) = 1.0;
t.matrix()(0, 1) = 0.0;
t.matrix()(1, 0) = 0.0;
t.matrix()(1, 1) = 1.0;
```

You can also use all the methods of the [Eigen Tensor](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/unsupported/group__CXX11__Tensor__Module.html) library to build these values.

Comment: Ok, It is the same conclusion that I got. For different reasons, I need to develop the execution part in C++, even because I developed the code to send request to server in C++. In documentation, I see that there are few or no C++ methods to retrieve a Tensor from a different format, like a string, an array or similar...

Comment: I added some details about how to do this using C++ - hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Your suggestions have been very useful. I saw that there is a constructor that accepts an Allocator pointer. Is there a method to pass a buffer with data allocated in the heap to this constructor so that the Tensor is automatically initialized with the data contained in the buffer? I wanna, for speed and efficiency issues, avoid copy if it is possible.

Comment: There is a pure-virtual `tensorflow::Allocator` interface that you can implement: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.h (though note that this is not technically part of the supported public interface, so it might change over time)